# Min/Max yAxis not working correctly in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I've 2 yAxis in demo, I set min/max value for both yAxis is min of 0, max of 200. But they don't work correctly. They are applied 250 for both.

Thanks

Comment: Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t04b3gjj/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I would expect endOnTick:false would sort the issue, but that didn't work on it's own.

I got it to work using endOnTick:false together with alignTicks:false.

```
   yAxis: [{
        max: 200,
        min: 0,
        alignTicks: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Primary Axis'
        }
    }, {
        max: 200,
        min: 0,
        alignTicks: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Secondary Axis'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true
    }],
```

Comment: Hi @SteveP.

Before, I tried alignTicks: false, it works for me. But I think I want to set alignTicks: true. We only resolve this problem by alignTicks: false, right ?
Could you give me some workarounds when I still want to alignTicks: true, please ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If you give both axes the same min/max then I don't think you will need alignTicks:true

Comment: Yes. But I want to set max/min of both axes for other cases that they are different value like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t04b3gjj/10/. But I think the right axis don't display properly for me :). Because it isn't align with the left axis.